# React Native APK keep crashing on device after releasing, but on build it's working fine

Tags: android, reactjs, build.gradle, react-native

I created a signed react-native apk after following all the documents from the official react native documentation ( i.e. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android ). After creating my app crashed.

I have tried this doc also:
https://medium.com/@impaachu/react-native-android-release-build-crash-on-device-14f2c9eacf18

Here is My adb Logcat :

```
        08-20 16:00:30.003  1724  1982 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Result has already been set!
        08-20 16:00:30.003  1724  1982 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.common.futures.SimpleSettableFuture.checkNotSet(SimpleSettableFuture.java:118)
        08-20 16:00:30.003  1724  1982 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.common.futures.SimpleSettableFuture.setException(SimpleSettableFuture.java:42)
        08-20 16:00:30.003  1724  1982 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerImpl$23.onFailure(DevSupportManagerImpl.java:953)
        08-20 16:00:30.003  1724  1982 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.WebsocketJavaScriptExecutor$1.onFailure(WebsocketJavaScriptExecutor.java:83)
        08-20 16:00:30.003  1724  1982 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.WebsocketJavaScriptExecutor$2$1.onFailure(WebsocketJavaScriptExecutor.java:121)
        08-20 16:00:30.003  1724  1982 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSDebuggerWebSocketClient.abort(JSDebuggerWebSocketClient.java:240)
        08-20 16:00:30.003  1724  1982 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSDebuggerWebSocketClient.onFailure(JSDebuggerWebSocketClient.java:215)
        08-20 16:00:30.003  1724  1982 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.failWebSocket(RealWebSocket.java:571)
        08-20 16:00:30.003  1724  1982 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$2.onResponse(RealWebSocket.java:216)
        08-20 16:00:30.003  1724  1982 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:206)
        08-20 16:00:30.003  1724  1982 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        08-20 16:00:30.003  1724  1982 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        08-20 16:00:30.003  1724  1982 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        08-20 16:00:30.003  1724  1982 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        08-20 16:00:30.235   844   955 E storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
        08-20 16:00:35.008  2097  2122 E BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for bluetooth
        08-20 16:00:35.688  2097  2122 E BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for bluetooth
        08-20 16:01:30.239   844   955 E storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
        08-20 16:02:30.241   844   955 E storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
        08-20 16:03:27.774  2097  2122 E BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for bluetooth
        08-20 16:03:30.243   844   955 E storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
        08-20 16:03:48.981  2097  2122 E BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for bluetooth
        08-20 16:03:49.404  2097  2122 E BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for bluetooth
        08-20 16:03:51.325  2097  2122 E BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for bluetooth
        08-20 16:03:53.196  2097  2122 E BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for bluetooth
        08-20 16:03:53.677  2097  2122 E BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for bluetooth
        08-20 16:04:30.244   844   955 E storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
        08-20 16:05:06.556  4157  4258 E ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.appmana

ger.nekodirect
```

Comment: Do you implement somekind of proguard?

Comment: @Giovanka please take a look my build.gradle



    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3]
   def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
   if (abi != null) {  
output.versionCodeOverride =  versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCod } }